# QEMu / KVM: error: Unable to add bridge tap0 port vnet0: Operation not supported

Tags: networking, qemu, linux-kvm, networkmanager, libvirt

In order to fully understand how the networking part works inside QEMU/KVM software virtualization environment, I decided to try to manually set up a the networking part, more or less simulating what `libvirt` does.

I'm using Arch, so there is not `ifupdown`. But anyways, first I created a tun/tap interface in the host with nmcli. When I check `ip link` and `ip a`, the tap0 interface is there. So far:

> host (tap0)

Then I used `dnsmasq` for that interface (intending to provide DHCP to VMs later on). So far:

> host (tap0) [DHCP]

Then I added this interface to `libvirt`. I figured I should [use the existing host bridge](https://libvirt.org/formatnetwork.html#examplesBridge) option as my interface would be ready already. The xml for libvirt is:

```
# cat /etc/libvirt/qemu/networks/tap0.xml
<network>
  <name>tap0</name>
  <forward mode='bridge'/>
  <bridge name='tap0'/>
</network>
```

Then using virsh I did `# net-define /etc/libvirt/qemu/networks/tap0.xml` and started the network tap0. So far:

> host (tap0) [DHCP] --> libvirt (tap0)

I figured that now I could add this interface to a VM and at least the VM would get IP address from the `dnsmasq` I have running on the host. I tried to add the interface to the VM by editing the VM with `virsh edit domain` and adding the following lines to the machine

```
<interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:55:ed:bf'/>
      <source bridge='tap0'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x01' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
```

I also tried

```
<interface type='network'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:55:ed:bf'/>
      <source network='tap0'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x01' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
```

, and I thought that at this point it would be like this:

> host (tap0) [DHCP] --> libvirt (tap0) <-- VM (eth0)

but when I try to start my VM it gives me this error:

```
virsh # start VM
```

> error: Failed to start domain arch error: Unable to add bridge tap0
>   port vnet0: Operation not supported

My end goal was to have `iptables` natting in and out traffic to my VM after it can get IP address correctly.

So, what am I missing?

Comment: See if [this message](https://www.redhat.com/archives/libvirt-users/2013-May/msg00043.html) and its [followup](https://www.redhat.com/archives/libvirt-users/2013-May/msg00069.html) help with your problem.

Comment: Please let me know if the above link was useful. If it was, I can post an answer.

Comment: Thank you for indicating it. I don't see how it applies. In the link they are using QEMU with OpenV Switch. I'm trying to create a tap interface and have it used by QEMU